# Camadas da aplicação e Web API 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, web-service, arquitetura-de-software

Estou com uma dúvida no planejamento e estruturação de minha aplicação e espero poder ouvir os mais experientes.

Hoje, no plano, tenho o acesso a dados (DAL) e a aplicação Web MVC 5 em camadas distintas e  sei que existe a grande necessidade de integração com outros sistemas.

Minha pergunta:

Seria uma boa criar uma camada Web API 2 entre a DAL e Web MVC 5?

A ideia é centralizar a forma de acesso aos dados, seja pela aplicação interna ou por terceiros. Creio que isso facilitaria a manutenção, certo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vejo três fatores a se considerar:

1. Se os dados precisam estar expostos a terceiros via HTTP essa arquitetura é um pré-requisito, não um opcional.
2. Se sua aplicação não precisa de níveis de acessos diferentes daqueles planejados para a api (a ponto de ser necessário fazer maracutaias na api), também não vejo por que seguir outro caminho.
3. Uma API adiciona uma camada entre aplicação e banco, e essa camada tem um custo. Esse custo só é considerável se sua aplicação for missão crítica (não me parece que seja). Mas veja, é um custo considerável, mas não inviabiliza.

Comment: A integração deverá acontecer no projeto, mas não necessariamente em seu lançamento. Pode ser um projeto a parte. Estou pensando em manter as camadas DAL, Aplicação e futuramente eu crio uma Web API que utiliza o DAL para expor os dados (XML ou JSON). Desta forma eu mantenho a aplicação acessando o DAL (evitando o item 3 que você mencionou e isso me preocupa) e centralizado o acesso ao banco.

Comment: Eu faria dessa forma, manteria um projeto DAL pois ele independe da API. Desenvolveria mais dois projetos independentes: um website e uma API. Se inicialmente o website conecta-se diretamente a DAL não é importante, a qualquer momento eu poderia migrar para a API.